# How to add global resource to specify output XML xsd format in MapForce?

Tags: xml, mapping, map-force, xml-generation

I started learn about MapForce couple of days back and I was able to create some simple mapping to generate XML file from csv file. But my problem is how can we use MapForce global resources to specify XML xsd format?

[This is sample XML which I generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBk3U.png)

But I saw that couple of resources which show this can be loaded from MapForce global resources.

Please can someone have experience on adding global resources in to specify the xsd file in MapForce mapping (In XML output), can you share the way it can be implemented.

I try to add resource as mentioned in below reference

http://manual.altova.com/mapforce/mapforcebasic/index.html?mffdefining__adding_a_global_reso.htm

[This is the global resource which I try to add in to the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X9Nh.png)

But when I try to preview the mapping it gives [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5ODg.png).